# Android Custom View onMeasure onDraw lifecycle

Tags: android, view, ondraw

I have created a custom view in android which extends View. I override the onDraw() method and do my painting to the canvas there - no problem.

I understand that I should override the onMeasure() method as well and call setMeasuredDimension(width, height) with my desired dimensions.

I notice that if I position breakpoints in my code, onMeasure() fires before onDraw().

Now my problem is that I don't know my view's desired height until onDraw has finished executing. My height starts off as a default value of 100 and then gets set at the end of onDraw - but onMeasure has already been executed before this so my View is only 100 px high.

How do I design my view so that it gets re-measured after onDraw() so that the height of my view can be determined dynamically?

Comment: you can call invalidate after you know what size you are

Comment: I think you should look at refactoring you code such that 'onMeasure' knows how tall your custom view will be. It's also the more logical place to do this calculation and it's aptly called 'onMeasure'.

Comment: @njzk2 Calling invalidate at the end of your onDraw() simply schedules another pass of onDraw - so you get stuck in a never ending loop of onDraw -this does not cause the parent view to call onMeasure again.

Comment: i mistook this method for requestLayout, i think

Comment: @CodePoet This would I guess be the optimum solution. The Widget I am creating is a TextView which can wrap text around a given set of bitmaps. The height of the view is calculated as the text is rendered and is (as you can image) very computationally expensive. But as you say I shall have to try to refactor this if no-one can suggest an alternative

Comment: @njzk2 requestLayout() did the trick - thank you very much

Comment: It isn't an official document, but https://plus.google.com/u/0/+ArpitMathur/posts/cT1EuBbxEgN recently came up on Google+. The comments also have a good discussion with some detailed explanation